# How do I do a group by on an if statement on a column in Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have a Spark SQL query where I want to do something like

select (if colA='' , "no data","data"),count(*) from table group by  (if colA='' , "no data","data")

I have Spark 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it using the alias for your computation column:-

SELECT (IF colA='' , "no data","data") as newcol,count(*) from table group by newcol

Thanks,
Charles.